# WordPress How to link a button to a specific template page?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a website with several pages with links/buttons that should lead to a specific page.
Is there a way to link this buttons in a dynamic way, that does not include page ID?

Currently I am doing it this way, with ACF field in which I write in a page ID

```
  <div class="projects-homepage-item">
                            <?php $projects_page = get_post(get_field('page_id')); ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink($projects_page->ID); ?>" class="projects-homepage-item-img" target="_blank">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
```

Is there something similar to this function that leads to blog/post page?

```
  <div class="news-homepage-btn-wrapper">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink(get_option('page_for_posts'))); ?>" target="_blank" class="news-homepage-btn"><?php printf(__('Pogledaj sve novosti', 'femix')); ?></a>
            </div>
```

Comment: When I need something like this I use ACF Option Pages. Add a field there that is a post (or similar) and it effectively becomes a global that you can use as `get_field("checkout_url", "options")`